# Validate inputs when I do ajax post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-validate

I am working on ASP.Net MVC 2 application. I need to validate below mentioned pop up by using jQuery because I am sending that data using an AJAX call as below.

Note : I am **not using any form element** for my UI

```
addButton.off('click').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/incentives/CreditPackagesAdd",
        data: dataPost,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (url) {
        }
    });
});
```

My Pop up window is as below:

[image]

My UI Html code is as below :

```
<div class="dialog form simpleForm slimForm" id="add-package" data-width="350" data-title="Add Credit Package">

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="name">
                        Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="value">
                        Value</label>
                    <input type="number" name="value" id="value" /></li>
                <li>
                    <label for="purchasePrice">
                        Purchase Price</label>
                    <input type="number" name="purchasePrice" id="purchasePrice" /></li>
                <li>
                    <label for="expirationPeriod">
                        Good for</label>
                    <%: Html.PopUp<ExpirationPeriod>("expirationPeriod") %></li>
                <li>
                    <label for="valid">
                        Start Date</label>
                    <input type="date" class="datePicker" name="valid" id="valid" value="<%: DateTime.Today.ToString("M/d/yyyy") %>"
                        data-min="<%: DateTime.Today.ToString("M/d/yyyy") %>" /></li>
                <li>
                    <label for="expiration">
                        Expiration</label>
                    <input type="date" class="datePicker" name="expiration" id="expiration" data-min="<%: DateTime.Today.ToString("M/d/yyyy") %>" /></li>
                <li>
                    <label for="purchasedByCustomer">
                        Cannot be Purchased By Customer</label>
                    <%:Html.CheckBox("isPurchasedByCustomer")%>
                </li>
                <li class="buttons">
                    <button type="button" id="addButton" class="actionButton default">
                        Add</button></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

My questions are:

1. I know I am unable to validate my inputs by using DataAnotations. So how can I do that by using Jquery?
2. Or Any jquery library for this kind of validation ?
3. Or Suggest any other method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the data elements you need to validate?

Comment: @ATOzTOA I need to validate all form inputs.such as Name ,Value (decimal),Price (decimal) like that for basic input validations.Both at data entering time as well as when I click "Add" button(i.e. Ajax post time)

Comment: Please post your `form` code.

Comment: @ATOzTOA I have updated my UI code. Actually My UI code is not inside the form tags.It's a code without form element.

Comment: Updated my answer as per your elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function to check the various text boxes...

```
function validateData() {
    // Name
    var n  = $("#name").value;
    if (n == null || n == "") {
        alert("Please fill out name.");
        return false;
    }

    isprice = /^\d+\.\d{2}$/;

    // Value
    var val  = $("#value").value;

    if (val == null || val == "") {
        alert("Please fill out name.");
        return false;
    } else if(!isprice.test( val )) {
        alert("Please enter valid data for Value.");
        return false;
    }   

    // Purchase Price
    var price  = $("#purchasePrice").value;

    if (price == null || price == "") {
        alert("Please fill out name.");
        return false;
    } else if(!isprice.test( price )) {
        alert("Please enter valid data for Purchase Price.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Then modify your AJAX call like this:

```
addButton.off('click').on('click', function () {
    if(validateData()) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/incentives/CreditPackagesAdd",
            data: dataPost,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (url) {
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry.I am not familiar with javascript and also whole our code base has been done by using jquery.So I must need jquery solution.And also I don't have any form element defined in this popup.

Comment: Any way I can convert it to jquery. My problem is Can I achieve above solution without form element ?

Comment: Yes your solution is OK. But do you know any jquery plugin which we can use without manually doing all validations ? In other words such a plugin will automatically reflect the DataAnotations which we did for the properties .Kind of that ? Any idea ?

Comment: OK, there is a jquery plugin "Validation" [ link : http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ ], but it will only validate a form. Why can't you place everything you have inside a form and use it?

Comment: Yes sure I will check and let you know.Thanks for support.

Answer (score 1):

This will fire form validation

```
$('form').submit(function(evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
var $form = $(this);
if($form.valid()) {
    //Ajax call here
}
});
```

**Updated**

```
addButton.off('click').on('click', function () {
   if($("form").valid())
   {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/incentives/CreditPackagesAdd",
        data: dataPost,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (url) {
           }
         });
    }
});
```

Comment: What kind of jquery setup should I do before ?

Comment: you just need to include jquery plugin.

Comment: @DON Here you have mentioned Form submit event.I need to do it at ajax call (asynchronous way) ? Any Idea ?

Comment: you can even add this condition on `button` click before your ajax call `$('form').valid()`

Comment: @DON Then is it fire DataAnotations which I set or should I do something else ?

Comment: @DON above you have mentioned about some validation jquery plugin.Could you put url for that plugin ?

Comment: @Sampath, no need you are already using that plugin. Have you tried the updated code? It will work.

Comment: @DON Could I achieved above solution without form element ?

Comment: @Sampath, Why do you need this? Every HTML elements must be inside `Form`

Comment: @DON No. Actually in asp.net mvc we can have html elements without form element.Such a example is popup window.In MVC we use form elemnt only when we need to do full page post like you have showed.All other scenarios we don't need.By using jquery we can pass data into server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22510/discussion-between-don-and-sampath)